# What is the significance behind the apples and boxes?

Tags: symbolism, mawaru-penguindrum

In the show, the box and apple motifs reoccur throughout Mawaru Penguindrum.

What are the significance the two? Does it tie into the plot in any way?

[image: Apples]

Answer (score 5):

I haven't seen it myself, but apples can often symbolize sexuality, temptation ("forbidden fruit") , fertility ("bearing fruit" as in your screenshot).

Connections can also be made to the stories of Adam & Eve and Sleeping Beauty.

The circular shape of an apple can also be a depiction of loops, or eternity - which is what it appears to be in Penguindrum:

> It is revealed in the finale that the apple is a metaphor for the Penguindrum, which seems to be Kanba's life, shared between the three siblings

([TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/MawaruPenguindrum))

[This article is more indepth about the apples in Penguindrum](http://snippettee.wordpress.com/2011/11/27/afterthoughts-on-mawaru-penguindrum-apples-and-its-symbolisms/)